# How to put alert value to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

in this code i am trying to get the alert value to the element.

brief:
my ajax code checks the database values and gets the new values from database and 
displays the fetched values in alert. but i am not able to put that alert values into 
element...

How can i do this?

Code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#refresh").click(function(){
                   var fileId=id;
                   var rowNum = $(this).parent().parent().index();;
                   $.ajax({
                   type:"post",
                    url:"checkStatusAndNumRecs",
                   data:{fileId:fileId},
                    success:function(data)
                   {

                    setTimeout(alert(data), 2000);
                    var allTds = $("#rtable tr:eq('"+rowNum+"')").find('td');
                    $(allTds)[4].html(data[0]);               
                    $(allTds)[3].html(data[1]);
                    document.getElementById("#div1").innerHTML=data;

               },
               error:function(data)
               {
                document.getElementById("#div1").innerHTML="It was a failure !!!";
               }
                });
                });
                });
        </script>
```

HTML code:

```
<td><div id="div1"><s:property value="%{#m.status}" /></div></td>
```

In `alert(data)` i am getting the value.
but when i put same value like this

```
document.getElementById("#div1").innerHTML=data;
```

it is not applying the value to element

Comment: have you tried with the jquery way: $('#div1').html(data);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need `#` using javascript's `getElementById`
try this

```
 document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=data; //notice no `#` in front of div1
```

**or**

using jquery that should be

```
 $('#div1').html(data);
```

Comment: even after not using your code it is not applying to element.

Answer (score 1):

try

document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=data[0];
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML=data[1];

or

$('#div1').html(data[0]);
$('#div2').html(data[1]);

Pass the actual data inside the object to the HTML element, not the object itself.